# How to delete all folders and files in a directory except a specific folder in PHP

Tags: php

How can I delete all folders and files except a specific folder?

```
uploaded->
.      folder_A->
.      .         folder_A1   //empty folder
.      .         folder_A2   //full folder 
.      .         img.png     // a file
.      .
.      folder_B //empty
.      .
.      folder_c->
.      .         folder_c1   //empty folder
.      .         file.doc    // a file
.      .
```

I want remove all folders and file in it inside **"uploaded"** folder except a specific folder that I determined.
For example I want remove all folders and files except **folder_c**

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal?

Comment: writing code would be a good start, then `if (is this the folder I don't want to delete?) then { don't delete it }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try like this

```
function Delete($path)
{
    if ((is_dir($path) === true) && ($path!='folder_c'))
    {
    $files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));

    foreach ($files as $file)
    {
        Delete(realpath($path) . '/' . $file);
    }

    return rmdir($path);
}

else if (is_file($path) === true)
{
    return unlink($path);
}

return false;
}
```

Hope this helps.